# Is surgery recommended for a first time dislocated shoulder?

Tags: pain, surgery, shoulder

Is surgery recommended for a first time dislocated shoulder after the shoulder has been put back in place? How is it best to heal this?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Since you are asking about general recommendations the question is not off-topic, but still the *best way to heal something* e.g. a dislocated shoulder should be assessed separately for each individual case, by a doctor, in person.

Answer (score 1):

Surgery is not always neccesary for the first time, depending on level of damage.

[NIH](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/patientinstructions/000524.htm)

> If this is the first time you dislocated your shoulder, you will
>   probably not need surgery.

- surgery

> If your shoulder continues to partly or fully dislocate in the future,
>   you may need surgery to repair or tighten the ligaments that hold the
>   bones in your shoulder joint together.

[WebMD](http://www.m.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/dislocated-separated-shoulder): Healing

> Ice your shoulder to reduce pain and swelling. Do it for 20-30 minutes
>   every three to four hours, for 2 to 3 days or longer. Use a sling or
>   shoulder immobilizer to prevent further injury until you get medical
>   treatment. Then follow the doctor's advice about whether or not to use
>   a sling. Take anti-inflammatory painkillers. Non-steroidal
>   anti-inflammatory drugs, or NSAIDs such as ibuprofen (Advil, Motrin)
>   or naproxen (Aleve), will help with pain and swelling. However, these
>   drugs may have side effects, like an increased risk of bleeding and
>   ulcers or heart attacks and strokes. They should not be used for
>   extended periods of time, unless your doctor specifically says
>   otherwise. Practice stretching and strengthening exercises if your
>   doctor recommends them.

Surgery is a treatment for shoulders that are badly damaged. It is unlikely that this level will come after the first dislocation.

Answer (score -2):

Surgery is not the first choise medical Interference in case of dislocated shoulder unless there is a significant damage to the joint and expectation to redislocation.

Comment: Same as with the other answer, we really need references. Thanks!